# Easy way to understand theta basis for X-cluster algebras of finite type?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, cluster-algebras

For $\mathcal A$-cluster algebras of finite type, it is very easy to describe the theta-basis: it consists of the cluster monomials. Is there any similarly easy way to describe the theta-basis for $\mathcal X$-cluster algebras?

For $\mathcal A$-cluster algebras not of finite type, the cluster monomials always form a subset of the theta-basis, and if the description I asked for above extends to the non-finite type case in a similar way, I would like to know that too, but I would still be very happy with an answer which doesn't say anything about non finite type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably the shortest answer, especially in finite-type:

**X-type theta functions are monomials times F-polynomials**

Making this precise is a bit fiddly, because there are multiple conventions and (more importantly) two different notions of `the' dual cluster algebra to an A-type cluster algebra:

- The "Fock-Goncharov dual" (sometimes called the cluster dual or the Langlands dual), which can be connected to the original algebra via an augmentation map
- The "GHKK dual" (sometimes called the mirror dual), which corresponds to the mirror dual directly constructed by the Gross-Siebert program.

They are closely related; if $B$ is the exchange matrix used to define one, the other is defined by $B^\top$. As a consequence, whenever $B$ is skew-symmetric and the full Fock-Goncharov conjecture holds, there is a twist isomorphism between them which sends theta functions to theta functions. However, even in this case, the set of theta functions have different parametrizations by the dual lattice $N$, and theta reciprocity only holds for the GHKK dual (without a twist of the parametrization).

With that caveat out of the way, I can tell you how to describe the X-type theta functions in the GHKK dual. If $\mathfrak{s}$ is the coefficient-free $A$-type seed defined by a skew-symmetrizable matrix $B$, then the GHKK dual theta function associated to $n\in N$ is

$$\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\vee}[n] = y^n F_{B^\top}[B^\top n] $$

where $F_{B^\top}[B^\top n]$ is the F-polynomial obtained by taking the A-type seed of $B^\top$, adjoining principal coefficients (denoted by $y$s), computing the A-type theta function $\vartheta_{B^\top}[B^\top n]$, and specializing the initial $x$-variables to $1$.

In finite-type, the theta functions correspond to cluster monomials and the F-polynomials here correspond to the F-polynomials of Fomin-Zelevinsky. The latter may be computed by any number of enumerative problems. For example, given a simply-laced Dynkin quiver, the F-polynomial will be a generating function of Euler characteristics of quiver Grassmannians.

---

**An example of this construction**

Let $B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. With the convention I'm using, the six A-type cluster variables are
\begin{align*}
\vartheta_\mathfrak{s}[1,0] &= x^{(1,0)} \\
\vartheta_\mathfrak{s}[0,1] &= x^{(0,1)} \\
\vartheta_\mathfrak{s}[-1,0] &= x^{(-1,0)}+x^{(-1,2)} \\
\vartheta_\mathfrak{s}[0,-1] &= x^{(0,-1)}+x^{(-1,-1)}+x^{(-1,1)} \\
\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}}[1,-2] &= x^{(1,-2)} + 2x^{(0,-2)} + x^{(-1,-2)}+x^{(-1,0)} \\
\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}}[1,-1] &= x^{(1,-1)} + x^{(0,-1)}
\end{align*}
All theta functions are cluster monomials (products of adjacent pairs above). The scattering diagram and the Newton polytope of several theta functions (with a dot at $m$) are pictured below.

[image: B2 Scattering Diagram]

To cook up the F polynomials, we compute the six A-type cluster variables of $\mathsf{B}^\top=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ with principal coefficients.
\begin{align*}
\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\top}[1,0] &= x^{(1,0)} \\
\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\top}[0,1] &= x^{(0,1)} \\
\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\top}[-1,1] &= x^{(-1,1)}+y^{(1,0)}x^{(-1,0)} \\
\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\top}[-2,1] &= x^{(-2,1)}  + 2y^{(1,0)}x^{(-2,0)} + y^{(2,0)} x^{(-2,-1)}+y^{(2,1)}x^{(0,-1)} \\
\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\top}[-1,0] &= x^{(-1,0)}+y^{(1,0)}x^{(-1,-1)}+y^{(1,1)}x^{(1,-1)} \\
\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\top}[0,-1] &= x^{(0,-1)} + y^{(0,1)}x^{(2,-1)}
\end{align*}
and specialize the $x$-variables to $1$:
\begin{align*}
    F_{B^\top}[1,0] &= 1 \\
    F_{B^\top}[0,1] &= 1 \\
    F_{B^\top}[-1,1] &= 1+y^{(1,0)} \\
    F_{B^\top}[-2,1] &= 1 + 2y^{(1,0)} + y^{(2,0)} + y^{(2,1)} \\
    F_{B^\top}[-1,0] &= 1+y^{(1,0)}+y^{(1,1)} \\
    F_{B^\top}[0,-1] &= 1 + y^{(0,1)}
\end{align*}
All other F-polynomials in this case can be computed as products of adjacent F-polynomials above; e.g.
$$
F_{B^\top}[-2,-1] = F_{B^\top}[-1,0]^2F_{B^\top}[0,-1]
=(1+y^{(1,0)}+y^{(1,1)})^2(1 + y^{(0,1)})
$$

The X-type theta function in the GHKK dual with $n=(1,-1)$ is then
\begin{align*}
    \vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\vee}[1,-1] 
    &= y^{(1,-1)}F_{B^\top}[-2,-1] \\
%    &= y^{(1,-1)}F_{B^\top}[-1,0]^2F_{B^\top}[0,-1] \\
    &= y^{(1,-1)}(1+y^{(1,0)}+y^{(1,1)})^2(1 + y^{(0,1)})
\end{align*}
We can check directly that theta reciprocity holds between $\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\vee}[1,-1]$ and each of the cluster variables on the $A$-type side.
$$\begin{array}{|c|ccccccc|}
\hline
m & (1,0) & (0,1) & (-1,0) & (0,-1) & (1,-2) & (1,-1) \\
\hline
\mathrm{val}_{(1,-1)}(\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}}[m]) 
& 1 & -1 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 1 \\
\hline
\mathrm{val}_{m}(\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\vee}[1,-1]) 
& 1 & -1 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Note that the latter row is given by the tropicalization of $\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\vee}[1,-1]$:
$$\mathrm{val}_{m}(\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\vee}[1,-1]) 
= (m_1-m_2) + 2\min(0,m_1,m_1+m_2)+ \min(0,m_2)
$$

Answer (score 3):

There's another answer which doesn't work in full generality, but is often easier to work with, especially if you know the A-type theta functions really well.

### When the exchange matrix has full rank, X-type theta functions are certain A-type theta functions after a change of variables

Specifically, let $B$ be an $d\times r$ extended exchange matrix whose rank is equal to its width $r$. Choose a skew-symmetrizable matrix $\widehat{B}$ whose first $r$-many columns are $B$, and let $B'$ denote the first $r$-many columns of $\widehat{B}^\top$. (Note that $B'$ does not depend on the choice of $\widehat{B}$, and $B'=B^\top$ if $B$ is square)

Let $\rho_{\widehat{B}^\top}:\mathbb{Z}[y^{\mathbb{Z}^d}]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x^{\mathbb{Z}^d}]$ be the ring homomorphism which sends $y^n$ to $x^{\widehat{B}^\top n}$. This is an *augmentation map* in the sense of Fock-Goncharov (or at least, it is when restricted to the cluster algebras/varieties).
Then
$$\rho_{\widehat{B}^\top}(\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\vee}[n])
= \vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}'}[\widehat{B}^\top n]
$$
where the latter theta function is an A-type theta function with exchange matrix $B'$.

In general, this doesn't determine the dual theta function. However, when $B$ has full rank (rank equal to its width), then this uniquely determines $\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\vee}[n]$, which can be computed by replacing each $x^{\widehat{B}^\top n}$ by $y^n$.

---

As an example, let
$$B =\widehat{B} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then $\rho_{\widehat{B}^\top}(y^{(n_1,n_2)}) = x^{(2n_2,-n_1)}$, and
$$ \rho_{\widehat{B}^\top}(\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\vee}[1,-1])
= \vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\top}[-2,-1]
$$
where the latter theta function is in the A-type cluster algebra of $B'=B^\top= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. One may compute that this is a cluster monomial; specifically,
\begin{align*}
\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\top}[-2,-1] 
&= \vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\top}[-1,0]^2\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\top}[0,-1]\\
&=(x^{(-1,0)}+x^{(-1,-1)}+x^{(1,-1)})^2( x^{(0,-1)} + x^{(2,-1)})\\
&= x^{(-2,-1)}(1+x^{(0,-1)}+x^{(2,-1)})^2( 1 + x^{(2,0)})
\end{align*}
The last expression has been factored so the exponent of each monomial is in the image of $\widehat{B}^\top$. Replacing each $x^{\widehat{B}^\top n}$ with $y^n$ yields the corresponding X-type theta function.
$$\vartheta_{\mathfrak{s}^\vee}[1,-1] 
= y^{(1,-1)}(1+y^{(1,0)}+y^{(1,1)})^2(1+y^{(0,1)})
$$